# JavaScript - Disable mouseup or fire on mousedown in echo3 framework?

Tags: javascript, onmousedown, onmouseup, echo3

Is there a way to disable/set to false the onMouseUp event in javascript so that when a button is clicked it fires on mousedown by default?

Comment: Mousedown is always fired before mouseup. Why would you disable the mouseup event?

Comment: Why not just use the onmousedown event as a trigger for whatever you're attempting to do instead? (What are you trying to achieve?)

Comment: i mean like, so that it doesnt wait for you to release the mouse buttion, soon as you press it just does what its linked to as opposed to letting you hold down the mouse and drag off

Comment: Instead of using mouseup, use the click event. it's triggered on pressing the button, either by using the mouse or the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that onmousedown happens before onmouseup, you can't prevent an event from happening.  You can however prevent default behavior of an event by executing "preventDefault()" on the event object itself.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To be honest, I very much suspect there's a better way of achieving what you're after. I suspect if you update your question with some more surrounding information you'll get some good advice. :-)

Comment: I cant put event on onMouseDown because it fires from Java but this stupid echo3 framework doesnt have an equivalent of onMouseDown...

Comment: Ah... I'll update the tags and title of the question - sounds like a framework issue. :-)